# Call Multiple Functions onClick

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-databinding

Is it possible to call multiple functions onClick with Lambdas and Data Binding? Right now I have

```
android:onClick="@{()->ViewModel.doSomething()}
```

when I would like to accomplish

```
android:onClick="@{()->ViewModel.doSomething() and AnotherViewModel.doSomethingElse()}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Right now I can only add mathematical and boolean operators.